# Predict a factor of 3 levels and return the % of each factor

Tags: r, machine-learning, glm, predict

I am trying to predict a three-level factor with a set of variables. The group is A, B and C.

```
m<-glm(as.factor(Group)~Sex+BloodType+Pressure,data=Hel,family = "binomial")

newdata <- data.frame(Sex="M",BloodType="A+", Pressure=80)

predict(m,newdata)
```

and this returns:

```
        1 
0.7133324
```

I would like that to give me back:

```
A        B        C
20.00   40.00    40.000
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to use something that allows multinomial regression like nnet?

```
library(nnet)
trn = sample(1:nrow(iris),100)
fit_nnet <- multinom(Species ~ ., iris[trn,])

head(predict(fit_nnet,iris[-trn,],type="prob"))
      setosa   versicolor    virginica
7  1.0000000 2.348893e-11 2.166176e-58
9  0.9999323 6.765017e-05 2.438304e-52
10 0.9999940 6.035319e-06 1.530614e-56
12 1.0000000 1.355834e-09 1.315066e-57
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am using your code :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues to address:

First, `glm` can only do logistic regression with a two-level outcome. If you provide an outcome variable with more than two levels, it lumps all levels except the first (reference) level into the second level. To do multinomial regression, you'll need to use a different function (there are several packages that can do multinomial regression, for example, `polr` from the `MASS` package, `multinom` from the `nnet` package (see @Stupidwolf's answer), `vglm` from the `VGAM` package; also see the `mlogit` and `gmnl` packages).

Second, `predict(m1, newdata)` provides predictions on the log-odds scale. To get predictions on the probability scale, you would need to do `predict(m1, newdata, type="response")`. Similar options (though possibly with different names for the arguments and/or argument options) will need to be set to get predictions on the probability scale for multinomial models.

Comment: Thank you for your response!! :)